How to find all paths as a sequence of constraints in angr
I am trying to find all possible paths of all functions from binary executables as a sequence of symbolic expressions and constraints that are compatible with z3 or claripy from the start of any function to all possible end points the function might reach using angr. I cannot find any good resource on how to do it. Can someone provide a good solution to it or any resource that might be helpful? The angr documentation for symbolic execution is not complete as of this writing.
Thanks.
I have tried reading the docs and reading the source codes but angr is huge and sophisticated. Whatever I have tried did not turn up to something that I was looking for. I am expecting someone provide any solution to this or some link to some resources that might be helpful.
